# The relation does not exist in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, cakephp

I am have big problem with Postgresql.
I'm trying to insert record to postgres.
But i had error:
The relation "member_orderinfo2" does not exist. But this table had exist when i'm insert record.
This is my query to insert

```
insert into "member_orderinfo2"(order_id,slim_code,order_date,customer_order_number,ship_date,deliver_company,deliver_number,deliver_address,product_code,product_name,amount,unit_price,total_cost,order_customer_name,ship_status) values
(  '30059078','4170906','20131118','15754727-03直送','0','ﾒｰｶｰ直送','','京都府綾部市味方町１京ｾﾗｺﾐｭﾆｹｰｼｮﾝｼｽﾃﾑ','0996381','RD151-50SN(ｼﾞﾕｳﾘﾖｳﾀﾞ','5','5120.00','25600','梶野様','入荷待' )
```

What is error ???

Answer (score 0):

It looks like case sensitivity issue.

You used a double quotes for table name - "member_orderinfo2" - it means so table have to be named exactly **member_orderinfo2** with only lower chars. Double quotes are used for case sensitive identifiers. Usually better don't use it when it is possible - are necessary when used identifier is keyword - so don't use case sensitive identifiers and don't use keywords as identifiers.

Comment: When i remove "" it's had same error. When i'm using pgAdmin to insert, it success. I'm get data from csv file. It had 100 record. Just only 3 record had this error.

Comment: Then there are two other possibilities - you use different database (different server) or different path. Recheck your connection parameters, please.

Comment: I'm using only one database to run this query. My data had 100 record just only 3 record can not insert because this error.

Comment: there is a possibility to use a wrong encoding - so identifier can be broken by some invisible chars.

Comment: My databse using UTF-8 and my csv file is sjis . I'm had use function mb_convert_encoding to encode it.